# How to bring back the top menu bar on 16.04 terminal?

Tags: 16.04, gnome

It seems after upgrading to 16.04 (from 15.10) gnome-terminal no longer displays menu entries ("File", "Edit", etc.) in the global top menu, but in the per-window menu instead. I much prefer an Apple-style global menu (like other Ubuntu apps have) so is there a way to bring it back?

Comment: Here you go: https://www.techgainer.com/show-menus-applications-window-instead-global-menu-bar/, and search before asking.

Comment: @mikewhatever Thanks but I have "Appearance > Behavior > Show the menus for a window" set to "in the menu bar", and FF, LO etc display their menu just fine there; it's just gnome-terminal not behaving